# Trying to calculate weighted moving average but getting zero as result always

Tags: c#, weighted-average

I am trying to get out the "Weighted moving average" of a array of double values.

I have tried to get all peaces from some internet examples together but i always getting zero as result.

Problem is the calulation of "weight", its being zero but it should not be zero, example 1 / 107 = 0,0093457943925234 but the weight double values getting zero, i have tried change to long and decimal and getting the same problem.

Any ideas?

```
    public static double WeighteedMovingAverage(double[] data)
    {
        double aggregate = 0;
        double weight;
        int item = 1;

        int count = data.Count();

        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            weight = item / count;
            aggregate += d * weight;
            count++;
        }

        return (double)(aggregate / count);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
weight = (double)item / (double)count;
```

need to be `double` to avoid casting before operation

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double WeighteedMovingAverage(double[] data)
{
    double aggregate = 0;
    double weight;
    int item = 1;

    int count = data.Count();

    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        //replace with line below weight = item / count;
        weight = (double)item / (double)count;
        aggregate += d * weight;
        count++;
    }
    //replace with line below return (double)(aggregate / count);
    return (double)(aggregate / (double)count);
}
```

Comment: the return statement should be fine as it is since the dividend is a double